# Running Issue on SEctractor

Tags: image, image-processing, astronomy, reduction, fits

I got this bug while running SExtractor

`----- SExtractor 2.28.0 started on 2023-12-04 at 16:30:12 with 1 thread

> Reading Neural Network Weights
> *Error*: SOM file not found: default.som

`

But I didn't have this bug before, I just ran again the same fits. How can I solve this problem? thanks.

I rewrite the default.sex. But I copy the fits to another folder and another default.sex files, and it works. I have no idea where the bug come from.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the `default.som` file that you want/need ? This is marked 'Experimental' and only appears in the config file if you generate the extended version of the config file using `sex -dd`:

```
#--------------------------- Experimental Stuff -----------------------------

PSF_NAME         default.psf    # File containing the PSF model
PSF_NMAX         1              # Max.number of PSFs fitted simultaneously
PATTERN_TYPE     RINGS-HARMONIC # can RINGS-QUADPOLE, RINGS-OCTOPOLE,
                                # RINGS-HARMONICS or GAUSS-LAGUERRE
SOM_NAME         default.som    # File containing Self-Organizing Map weights
```

I can't find the file in the github repository either even though there is a `som.c` and `som.h` that would use it. The file that is more normally used is the `default.nnw` file which is used for the Star/Galaxy separation:

```
#------------------------- Star/Galaxy Separation ----------------------------
 
SEEING_FWHM      1.2            # stellar FWHM in arcsec
STARNNW_NAME     default.nnw    # Neural-Network_Weight table filename
```

The output in your question also talks about the "Neural Network Weights" which makes me think that it's this file that you actually want. It should be included in the distribution for SExtractor but you could get it from [github](https://github.com/astromatic/sextractor/blob/master/config/default.nnw) if needed. The other config files referenced in the `default.sex` namely `default.param, default.conv, default.nnw`, need to be in the same directory (or you need to modify the references in the `default.sex` to include the full path to the file). I would also comment out the reference to the `SOM_NAME` variable and the `default.som` file as they don't seem to be ready for prime time.